# Как выделить диапазоны чисел из массива?

Tags: массивы, php7

Мучаюсь уже час, не получается выделить диапазоны из массива.
Допустим, есть массив `[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,9,13,20]`. На выходе хочу получить строку `0-3,5-7,9,13,20`.
Пробовал циклом проходить по массиву и с помощью `next` и `prev` заменять числа на тире или добавлять запятую, но выходит какая-то фигня. Подскажите, наверняка есть простые алгоритмы для этой задачи или хелпер в Yii2?

Comment: Является ли последовательность только из двух следующими друг за другом числами различающимися на 1 интервалом? Т.е какой ответ ожидается из массива `[0,1,3]` -> `0-1,3` или `0,1,3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вот примитивненько через цикл, просто на php :)

```
function array_to_string($arr) {
    sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $kk = count($arr);
    $result = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $kk; $i++) {
        if (isset($arr[$i])) {
            if (!count($a)) {
                $a[] = $arr[$i];
                continue;
            }
            if ($arr[$i] == end($a) + 1) {
                $a[] = $arr[$i];
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (count($a) < 3) {
            $result .= implode(',', $a) . ',';
        } else {
            $result .= reset($a) . '-'. end($a) . ',';
        }
        if (isset($arr[$i])) {
            $a = [$arr[$i]];
        }
    }

    return trim($result, ',');
}

echo array_to_string([0,1,2,3,5,6,7,9,13,20]) . "<br>\n";
echo array_to_string([0,1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,20,21]) . "<br>\n";
```

Результат

```
0-3,5-7,9,13,20
0,1,3,5-13,20,21
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что нужно. Правда, я представил результат в виде массива, а не строки и вместо trim по запятой сделал implode. Получилось таким образом добавить пробелы после запятых.

Answer (score 1):

**Первый вариант:**

```
$myArray = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,9,13,20];

//last value is dropped so add something useless to be dropped
array_push($myArray, null);
$rangeArray = array();

array_walk($myArray, function($val) use (&$rangeArray){
    static $oldVal, $rangeStart;

    if (is_null($rangeStart))
        goto init;

    if ($oldVal+1 == $val) {
        $oldVal = $val;
        return;
    }

    if ($oldVal == $rangeStart) {
        array_push($rangeArray, $rangeStart);
        goto init;
    }

    array_push($rangeArray, $rangeStart . '-' . $oldVal);

    init: {
        $rangeStart = $val;
        $oldVal = $val;
    }
});

echo '<pre>'.print_r($rangeArray, true).'</pre>';
```

**Второй вариант:**

```
$numbers = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,9,13,20];

$ranges[] = array($numbers[0],$numbers[0]); // initial value

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  $range    = array_pop($ranges);
  $extend   = ($range[1] == $number-1);
  $ranges[] = array($range[0],$extend ? $number : $range[1]);
  if (!$extend) $ranges[] = array($number,$number);
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($ranges,TRUE).'</pre>';
```

будет содержать массив такого вида:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 7
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 13
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 20
        )
)
```

то есть из него видно, что если элемент в ячейке 0 и 1 одинаковый - значит он уникальный, если разные - значит это диапазон. Отфильтровать это можно потом так:

```
foreach ($ranges as $range) {
  $output[] = ($range[0] == $range[1]) ? $range[0] : $range[0].'-'.$range[1];
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($output,TRUE).'</pre>';
```

будет уже выводить

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-3
    [1] => 5-7
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 13
    [4] => 20
)
```

---

Примеры взяты из https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80080/aggregate-array-values-into-ranges

Там же можно посмотреть еще парочку примеров.

Comment: Второй вариант у вас на нулевой позиции возвращает массив с двумя нулями, а на 1ой позиции снова идет возврат нуля.

Comment: AAAAAAAA, goto!

Comment: @Etki что, страшно?) Волков боятся в лес не ходить)

Comment: там-то они и накидываются

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, есть более оптимальное решение, но на скорую руку получился вполне годный код. Комментариев больше написал, чем кода...

```
//упорядоченный входной массив
$arr = [0,2,3,5,6,7,9,13,15,16,17,20];

//сюда будем складывать ranges: ["0","2-3","5-7",...]
$ranges = [];
//а в этой переменной будем хранить текущий range: [from, to]
$currentRange = [$arr[0],$arr[0]];

//перебираем со второго элемента и до +последнего
for($i = 1; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
    //на последней итерации, когда $i > count($arr), просто закроем последний range
    if(!isset($arr[$i])) {
        $ranges[] = $currentRange[0] !== $currentRange[1] ? implode('-', $currentRange) : $currentRange[0];
    } else {
        //если последний элемент текущего range равен "текущее значение - 1" - продляем range на текущий элемент
        if ($currentRange[1] === intval($arr[$i]) - 1) {
            $currentRange[1] = $arr[$i];
        } else {
            //закрываем текущий range (скидываем в ranges новую строку)
            $ranges[] = $currentRange[0] !== $currentRange[1] ? implode('-', $currentRange) : $currentRange[0];
            //открываем новый range с текущего места
            $currentRange = [$arr[$i], $arr[$i]];
        }
    }
}

//склеиваем результирующий массив в строку через запятую
$resultStr = implode(',', $ranges);
```